# Conflicting sizes for dimension 'time' with rioxarray

Tags: geotiff-tiff, netcdf, xarray, rioxarray

I've been using rioxarray to convert netcdf files to geotiffs, and up till now, it's worked great.

However, when I open a [ERA5](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-land?tab=overview) reanalysis netcdf dataset, rioxarray appears to find that the data size and the 'time' dimension are different (72144 vs 32768):

```
>> data = rio.open_rasterio(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rioxarray/_io.py", line 756, in open_rasterio
    result = DataArray(
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py", line 344, in __init__
coords, dims = _infer_coords_and_dims(data.shape, coords, dims)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py", line 152, in _infer_coords_and_dims
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 32768 on the data but length 72144 on coordinate 'time'
```

When I open the same file in xarray, however, I find that the 'time' dimension and the data length are equal (72144):

```
>> xdata = xr.open_dataset(filename)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 53, longitude: 89, time: 72144)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 20.0 20.25 20.5 20.75 ... 41.5 41.75 42.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 55.0 54.75 54.5 54.25 ... 42.5 42.25 42.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-01-01 ... 2020-12-31T23:00:00
Data variables:
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
>> xdata.t2m.shape
(72144, 53, 89)
```

Why might rioxarray think the 'time' dimension in my netcdf is too short for the data, when xarray thinks the dimension and the data are the same size?

Comment: Sounds like a potential bug. Mind opening up an issue on github?

Comment: @snowman2 I'm actually not able to reproduce this bug in any test data set I can share - I'm inclined to write it off as a data corruption issue and close this question.

Comment: Encountered the same issue with an ERA5-Land NetCDF dataset. Previously I was loading it with the netcdf4 module which seemed to be working fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for it?